# Getting list of elements from web listbox

Tags: excel, listbox, vba

I'm trying to count all elements in a listbox on a webpage (eventually loop through them, but solving this issue will help with looping):

[image]

Im quite new to VBA, but i do believe this is a listbox object, as in firebug name of this object has "listbox" at the end.

All the suggestions i found here or elsewhere related to either .ListCount or .ListIndex
Somehow, either of these result in error 438, object not supported.

Piece of code below. 
Can you suggest please?

```
With IE.document
  .getElementById("xxx_startDay").Value = "1"
  .getElementById("xxx_startMonth").Value = "JAN"
  .getElementById("xxx_startYear").Value = "2017"

  .getElementById("xxx_endDay").Value = "31"
  .getElementById("xxx_endMonth").Value = "JAN"
  .getElementById("xxx_endYear").Value = "2017"

  'IE.document.getElementById("xxx_accountItemsListBox").Focus

  Set listMPAN = IE.document.getElementById("xxx_accountItemsListBox")

  listMPAN.selectedIndex = 5

  MsgBox (listMPAN.ListCount)

End With
```

Comment: Perhaps you can loop through them with for I = 1 to webList.listcount?

Comment: I must have been unclear - .ListCount causes 438 error.

Answer (score 0):

Help was closer than i thought.
Turned out the ListBox was not the real listbox, it was some other html element with listbox generated on the server side (just trying to repeat what i was told):

```
<select size="4" name="xyz" multiple="multiple" id="xxx_accountItemsListBox" class="accountItemsListBox">
```

so the .ListCount wasnt recognised. Instead i had to use .Length and

```
msgbox(listMPAN.Length)
```

worked perfectly. Now looping through it should be simple.
Thank you.

Comment: Good!  Yes, it is not a listbox in HTML, usually a select element.

Answer (score 0):

This was my alternative answer:

```
On Error GoTo endCount

For i = 0 To 100
    Debug.Print myDoc2.getElementById("quoteDropdown").Item(i).Value
Next i



endCount:
On Error GoTo 0

If i <> 0 Then

    Debug.Print "there are  " & i & " options."
End If
```